How to build in Mistral model into LocalAI permanently?
I would like to create a Dockerfile, in which I would run LocalAI with built in Mistral model inside.
I'm wondering, if its possible to built in Mistral model into LocalAI image permanently? Here's my current solution, which gives me only: 10.21 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused. Here's my Dockerfile:
FROM localai/localai:v2.15.0-aio-cpu

# Define a volume for storing data
VOLUME /build/models

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      curl

ENV LOCALAI=http://localhost:8080

RUN curl --retry 10 --retry-connrefused --retry-delay 1 http://localhost:8080/ && \
    curl $LOCALAI/models/apply -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"url": "github:mudler/LocalAI/gallery/mistral-0.3.yaml", "name": "mistral-0.3" }'

The error is:
➜  test docker build -f Dockerfile . -t localaimistralimg
[+] Building 10.8s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                           docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 540B                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/localai/localai:v2.15.0-aio-cpu                                                            0.5s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/localai/localai:v2.15.0-aio-cpu@sha256:762e705791391d2eb80039832ad31d6d5a896998a6da6a8a72fcee93810e7283      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/3] RUN apt-get update &&     DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive     apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes    0.0s
 => ERROR [3/3] RUN curl --retry 10 --retry-connrefused --retry-delay 1 http://localhost:8080/ &&     curl http://localhost:8080/mo  10.2s
------                                                                                                                                     
 > [3/3] RUN curl --retry 10 --retry-connrefused --retry-delay 1 http://localhost:8080/ &&     curl http://localhost:8080/models/apply -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"url": "github:mudler/LocalAI/gallery/mistral-0.3.yaml", "name": "mistral-0.3" }':                    
0.182   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current                                                      
0.182                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed                                                        
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0                                                             
0.183 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
0.183 Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 1 seconds. 10 retries 
0.183 Warning: left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
1.185 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
1.185 Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 1 seconds. 9 retries 
1.185 Warning: left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
2.187 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
2.187 Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 1 seconds. 8 retries 
2.187 Warning: left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
3.189 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
3.190 Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 1 seconds. 7 retries 
3.190 Warning: left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
4.191 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
4.192 Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 1 seconds. 6 retries 
4.192 Warning: left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
5.194 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
5.195 Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 1 seconds. 5 retries 
5.195 Warning: left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
6.197 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
6.198 Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 1 seconds. 4 retries 
6.198 Warning: left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
7.200 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
7.201 Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 1 seconds. 3 retries 
7.201 Warning: left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
8.203 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
8.204 Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 1 seconds. 2 retries 
8.204 Warning: left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
9.206 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
9.206 Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 1 seconds. 1 retries 
9.206 Warning: left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
10.21 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
------
Dockerfile:14
--------------------
  13 |     
  14 | >>> RUN curl --retry 10 --retry-connrefused --retry-delay 1 http://localhost:8080/ && \
  15 | >>>     curl $LOCALAI/models/apply -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"url": "github:mudler/LocalAI/gallery/mistral-0.3.yaml", "name": "mistral-0.3" }'
  16 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c curl --retry 10 --retry-connrefused --retry-delay 1 http://localhost:8080/ &&     curl $LOCALAI/models/apply -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '{\"url\": \"github:mudler/LocalAI/gallery/mistral-0.3.yaml\", \"name\": \"mistral-0.3\" }'" did not complete successfully: exit code: 7

Is the following Dockerfile the only solution?
FROM localai/localai:v2.15.0-aio-cpu

# Define a volume for storing data
VOLUME /build/models

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      wget

ENV LOCALAI=http://localhost:8080

RUN wget https://github.com/mudler/LocalAI/blob/master/gallery/mistral-0.3.yaml -O models/mistral 
RUN wget https://huggingface.co/NousResearch/Hermes-2-Pro-Llama-3-8B-GGUF/resolve/main/Hermes-2-Pro-Llama-3-8B-Q4_K_M.gguf -O models/llama3

